# flutter multiselect not working or need something similar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, and am trying to create a dropdown box where the user can select multiple options or something similar to a dropdown box.  The only thing I have found on the internet is multiselect, but I can't get it to work.

I have tried making it the only child in my widget tree and also I have tried switching the versioning around in my pubsec.yaml file to no avail.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multiselect/flutter_multiselect.dart';

//void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(Choices()));
Future<Null> main() async {

runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    title: "multiselect help",
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: 'Choices',
    routes: {
      'Choices': (BuildContext context) => Choices(),
    },
  ),
);
}

class Choices extends StatefulWidget {
  Choices({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChoicesState createState() => _ChoicesState();
}

class _ChoicesState extends State<Choices> {
  String _value;
  String _value2;
  String _value3;
  List _myActivities = [];
  String _myActivitiesResult = '';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
           children: <Widget>[
      /*  DropdownButton<String>(
          items: [
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: "1",
              child: Text("1"),
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: "2",
              child: Text("2"),
          ),
          ],
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _value = value;
            });
          },
          hint: Text("Item"),
          value: _value,
        ),

    DropdownButton<String>(
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "1",
          child: Text("1"),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "2",
          child: Text("2"),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "3",
          child: Text("3"),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "4",
          child: Text("4"),
        ),

      ],
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _value2 = value;
        });
      },
      //new code
      hint: Text("#"),
      value: _value2,
    ),


*/
        MultiSelect(
  autovalidate: false,
  titleText: "hi",
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return 'Please select one or more option(s)';
    }
  },
  errorText: 'Please select one or more option(s)',
  dataSource: [
    {
      "display": "Australia",
      "value": 1,
    },
    {
      "display": "Canada",
      "value": 2,
    },
    {
      "display": "India",
      "value": 3,
    },
    {
      "display": "United States",
      "value": 4,
    }
  ],
  textField: 'display',
  valueField: 'value',
  filterable: true,
  required: true,
  value: null,
  onSaved: (value) {
    print('The value is $value');
  }
),





      ],
      ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  }

}






  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Next Page"),
      ),

      body: Choices()
    );
  }
```

In the expected results I would have a dropdown or something similar where I can make multiple selections.  The actual results show nothing, including not even showing the brother/sister widgets when they are not commented out.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with `Row`, layouts can sometimes end up with an infinite width, which is what's happening here. Luckily, the solution is simple. Just wrap the `MultiSelect` widget in the `Expanded` widget, and it will constrain the `MultiSelect` to only use the available width, and no more.

So

```dart
MultiSelect(...),
```

becomes

```dart
Expanded(
  child: MultiSelect(...),
),
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `Row` entirely and just put `MultiSelect` as a single Widget.

Comment: Thanks Sub6 Resources!!